# How to change the value attribute when I edit Input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to change the input type **value attribute** value when i edit input type.

```
<input type ="text" id="name" value ="abc">
```

When I edit the record in input type I want same time value attribute should be change like

suppose I am changing now value abc to xyz the value attribute value

should be value="xyz" how to change or how can I do it on blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `blur()` event something like this. Use browser's inspect element option to view the `value` attribute of the `input` text on changing the value to verify the working of the code.

```js
$('#name').blur(function(){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="text" id="name" value ="abc">
```

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla JS solution:

- Add an `evenListener` for `blur` and change the `value attribute`

```js
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('blur', function() {
  this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<input type ="text" id="name" value ="abc">
```